# Remove all lines except the last which start with the same string

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk

I'm using awk to process a file to filter lines to specific ones of interest. With the output which is generated, I'd like to be able to remove all lines except the last which start with the same string.

Here's an example of what is generated:

```
this is a line
duplicate remove me
duplicate this should go too
another unrelated line
duplicate but keep me
example remove this line
example but keep this one
more unrelated text
```

Lines 2 and 3 should be removed because they start with `duplicate`, as does line 5. Therefore line 5 should be kept, as it is the last line starting with `duplicate`.

The same follows for line 6, since it begins with `example`, as does line 7. Therefore line 7 should be kept, as it is the last line which starts with `example`.

Given the example above, I'd like to produce the following output:

```
this is a line
another unrelated line
duplicate but keep me
example but keep this one
more unrelated text
```

How could I achieve this?

I tried the following, however it doesn't work correctly:

```
awk -f initialProcessing.awk largeFile | awk '{currentMatch=$1; line=$0; getline; nextMatch=$1; if (currentMatch != nextMatch) {print line}}' -
```

Comment: your example is unclear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you read the file from the end to the beginning and print the first line containing `duplicate`? This way you don't have to worry about what was printed or not, hold the line, etc.

```
tac file | awk '/duplicate/ {if (f) next; f=1}1' | tac
```

This sets a flag `f` the first time `duplicate` is seen. From the second timem, this flag makes the line be skipped.

If you want to make this generic in a way that every first word is printed just the last time, use an array approach:

```
tac file | awk '!seen[$1]++' | tac
```

This keeps track of the first words that have appeared so far. They are stored in the array `seen[]`, so that by saying `!seen[$1]++` we make it True just when `$1` occurs for the first time; from the second time on, it evaluates as False and the line is not printed.

#### Test

```
$ tac a | awk '!seen[$1]++' | tac
this is a line
another unrelated line
duplicate but keep me
example but keep this one
more unrelated text
```

Comment: It's not just duplicate, it's any string that is repeated, see the example.

Comment: @bkmoney oh, thanks for the comment. Fixed it by making it more general

Comment: This does exactly what I was after. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could use an (associative) array to always keep the last occurence:

```
awk '{last[$1]=$0;} END{for (i in last) print last[i];}' file
```